# Why current ASP.NET MVC application root virtual path is not available in a another thread/Task?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task, virtual-path

One of my recent projects involved sending reminder e-mails based on some reminder configuration. E-mail sending is implemented in an asynchronous job using [Quartz.net.](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) and it requires to include a permalink to a entity in the application.

However, in order to get this permalink, I have to be able to compute the full URL, based on the identifier stored in the queue used for the job. The answer is not straightforward, since `HttpContext` is not available in the thread's context.

One solution is to store application root path in the queue and use it from there. Another way is to use a function like the following:

```
public static String GetCurrentBasePath(String prefix = "http://")
{
   return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
      prefix,                                           // protocol
      System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName,         // host
      System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath    // virtual application path
   );
}
```

However, this has (severe) limitations, since the protocol must be provided and also returns the `hostname`, not the `domain name`, thus rendering it useless when having multiple Web applications bound to the same host.

**The question: is Web application base path available in another thread/task?**. I think the other thread/task context is somehow connected to the `ApplicationPool`, rather than the `WebApp` and since multiple `WebApp`s can use the same `ApplicationPool`, there is not a direct connection between thread context and the `WebApp`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're invoking this. But from my experience, parallelism (as you've mentioned) loses the HttpContext. That said, there is nothing to stop you from using a config variable with the string value(s) that you need. Of course, depending how dynamic this value is this might not be the best course of action. But remember that the computation you're making above is expensive, so remember to store the value locally.

> I believe the best solution here (assuming you know the context values, which I don't see why you couldn't/wouldn't) would be to set some variables and avoid the computation altogether.

```
static readonly string hostName = "your-host";
static readonly string virtualPath = "your-virtual-path";
public static String GetCurrentBasePath(String prefix = "http://")
{
   return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
      prefix,                                           // protocol
      hostName,         // host
      virtualPath    // virtual application path
   );
}
```

Comment: I am using Quarz.net, but it is reproducible using a new thread, Task (TPL) or async/await. Basically, it is having jobs running in IIS instead of creating a Windows service or something similar.

Comment: Right. As I said, to me I think if you KNOW what the values you're attempting to compute are I think you're better off setting them as internal readonly values. Gives you thread-safety and saves you cycles.